# Attached files from MimeApplication, when downloaded results in formatless file, in python [MIMEApplication]

Tags: python, tkinter

```
msg['To'] = name + ' ' + sirname
msg['Subject'] = 'Testing subject'
msg['From'] = 'Silver Oak Group of Institutes'

text = 'blah'
file = open('blah.pdf','rb') 
msg.attach(text)
attach = MIMEApplication(file.read(),_subtype = 'pdf')
msg.attach(attach)
server.sendmail(email,receiver,msg.as_string())
```

Gmail, shows it as pdf. But when the blah.pdf is downloaded, it results in format less file.

Please bear with me, I an not a native english speaker, nor am I a professional stack overflow user.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with tkinter. I would also ask you to review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks edited the post.

Comment: You might want to update your tags too.